# Will Scope_Identity work in different application sessions?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My ASP.NET application is using SQL Server 2008 backend.

I have a Web Form which is used by many users simultaneously to enter records. When user clicks SAVE button, a stored procedure inserts record to the database. After the successful execution of this stored procedure, I want to pick the recent record ID of this user. That is, if I am inserting records, I want to pick only the ID of the last record entered by me and not of other user.

Will Scope_Identity work in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function from within the stored procedure itself. After it exits the function won't work.

You might want to consider the `OUTPUT` clause instead though to avoid the possibility of encountering [this bug in `Scope_Identity`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779).

Comment: How to use the OUTPUT clause?

Comment: @RPK `INSERT YourTable(YourColumnList) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (...);`. [Plenty of other examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: In regard to the OPs question, his ability to retrieve the correct value from Scope_Identity will be dependent on his implementation of the connection object he's using to his data source. He would need to be sure that he's retrieving the Scope_Identity with the same connection object he issued his insert with and didn't issue any other interfering commands in between the insert and retrieval.Perhaps this is already apparent but I wanted to stress that there is no necessary connection between an Application Session and a DB Session.

Comment: Ah I just noticed they said after executing the stored procedure. The answer will be "No" then. They will need to return scope identity from the stored procedure itself.